# Can you outrun light in general relativity?

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity

The top answer on [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/297468/gr-einsteins-1911-paper-on-the-influence-of-gravitation-on-the-propagation-of) explains that the speed of light can change with distance from an accelerated observer. Is there then in any meaningful sense a way to outrun light emitted from a distant source?

Comment: [You can outrun light even in special relativity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/244323/1325). Well, you need a rocket motor with an infinite supply of fuel, but that's a detail :-)

Comment: While you can create horizons and such by choosing a non-inertial frame, these are remote effects of your choice of frame, projections in the hyperbolic geometry. You can never outrun light in your local frame, no matter what you do. Neither in SR nor in GR. Photons of the flashlight you hold in your hand will always move away from you with the speed of light regardless of how you move or in what gravitational field you are.

Comment: @safesphere I explicitly say "Is there then in any meaningful sense a way to outrun light emitted from a *distant source*?" I'm not talking about flashlights in your hand. I'm well aware that locally the speed of light is still c.

Comment: My comment was intended to clarify John's comment that was not clear on this point. Other than that, as he said, if you move with acceleration, remote light may not catch up with you until you run out of fuel. Specifics depend on the case of course.