# Spacetime that allows matter to rotate faster-than-light

Tags: general-relativity, speed-of-light, faster-than-light

Is there a solution to Einstein's equations which allows:

1. the object to be rotating at sub-light speed when viewed from within itself.
2. for a distant observer the object to rotate at superluminal speed.

If so, I'd like to know what would be peculiar about looking at the outside world on that object, and when observing the object from a distance distance.

Comment: The (coordinate) speed of light is not invariant in GR. See [Does light really travel more slowly near a massive body?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/399738/does-light-really-travel-more-slowly-near-a-massive-body) for an explicit demonstration of this. So the answer to your question is _yes_. For example if you go close enough to a black hole you will observe even everyday objects to be moving faster than $c$.

Answer (score 0):

You already have to corotate with more than the speed of light if you are inside the [ergosphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ergosphere) of a rotating black hole, so that is not a boundary in relativity. The only thing you can't do is fly past someone else with more than the speed of light, so relative to all the objects you meet inside the ergosphere you will still have less than the speed of light since they are also forced to corotate, but relative to the far away stars [more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=938_TNP4aUs&t=5453s).

Comment: What happens to the case limited to rotation around a fixed axis?